# multiple select2 in a single php file to open a separate modal, second one not working

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, jquery-select2

Hi I am totally a newbie in php and i found a select2 to automatically populate dropdown, I would like to use it inside modal, first select2 inside its modal is working but the second one isnt working, here is my code  for the **FIRST ONE (Working)**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="prevprojmodal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <select class="substat form-control" style="width:500px" name="substat" style="min-width: 100%"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $('.substat').select2({
         allowClear: true,
         placeholder: 'Type to search for previous project',
         ajax: {
          url: 'ajax/getdata_previousproject.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          delay: 250,
          processResults: function (data) {
           return {
           results: data
         };
         },
         cache: true
         }
         });
         $('.substat').on('change', function() {
        var data = $(".substat option:selected").text();
        $("#projectprevioustest").val(data);
        })
</script>
```

And this is the code of the second one, but **NOT WORKING:**

**HTML**

```
<!-- Add Team Compo Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addteamcompomodal">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">

       <!-- Modal Header -->
       <div class="modal-header">
         <h4 class="modal-title">Add a member to Team</h4>
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
       </div>
       <!-- Modal body -->
       <div class="modal-body">

         <div class="form-group">
             <label> Staff Name </label>
             <select class="staffname form-control" name="staffname" id="staffname" placeholder="Staff Name"  style="width: 100%; padding: 0;"></select>
         </div>             

         <div class="form-group">
             <label> Percent Involvement </label>
             <input type="text" name="teampi" id="teampi" placeholder="Percent Involvement" class="form-control">
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
             <label> Specific Duties & Responsibilities </label>
             <input type="text" name="teamsdnr" id="teamsdnr" placeholder="Specific Duties & Responsibilities" class="form-control">
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
             <label> Specific Deliverables </label>
             <input type="text" name="teamsd" id="teamsd" placeholder="Specific Deliverables" class="form-control">
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
             <label> Project Role </label>
             <select required="" name="teampr" class="form-control" style="font-size: 12px;">
                 <?php
                 $resultatc = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM teamroles");
                 $resultatc->execute();
                 $checkRtc = $resultatc->rowCount();

                 if ($checkRtc > 0) {
                     echo "<option disabled='disabled' value = '' selected>SELECT</option>";
                     foreach ($resultatc->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH) as $disptc) {
                         for ($z = 0; $z < count($checkRtc); $z++) {
                             $disp_idtc = $disptc['tr_id'];
                             $disp_statustc = $disptc['tr_abb'];
                         }
                         echo "<option value='" . $disp_idtc . "'>" . utf8_encode($disp_statustc) . "</option>";
                     }
                 }
                 ?>
             </select>
         </div>


       </div>
       <!-- Modal footer -->
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="addRecord()">Save</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>

<!-- Add Team Compo Modal END-->
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.staffname').select2({
        dropdownParent: $('#addteamcompomodal')
        allowClear: true,
        placeholder: 'Type to Search for Staff',
        ajax: {
          url: 'ajax/getdata_staffteamcomp.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          delay: 250,
          processResults: function (data) {
            return {
          results: data
            };
          },
          cache: true
        }
      });

</script>
```

What should I be doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am assuming you want to add select2 feature to `select[name=teampr]` and the second JS code of select2 is for the same, then you can add class 'staffname' along with 'form-control' to `select[name=teampr]`. Please check and let me know for the result.

Comment: `select[name=teampr]` is ok. i just need `<select class="staffname` to be using the select2.

Comment: Yes, I just referenced the element. After adding the class to the select tag, did it work?

Comment: No still same..